# Neumann KM 184 ORTF Røde Blimp

Tags: neumann, rode, blimp, stereo

I want to try a pair of Km184 for field recording next week and can´t find any informations about packing them inside a Røde Blimp in ORTF Setup. Does anyone of you found a way to do this ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Not KM184s, but it's kinda the same setup I guess:
http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.de/2011/10/semi-stealth-recording-with-my-new-cm3s.html

I did the same thing with CM3s in a Rycote windshield a few days ago and have to say, that the mics were pretty vulnerable to wind. I guess this comes from the small distance between the capsules and the windshield. 
Therefore you should strongly try to avoid wind.

You might want to build yourself some shortened XLR-plugs, so that you are a bit more flexible in adjusting the angle of the mics (don't know how long the KM184s are compared to the CM3).

[image]

I cut away the ends of a XLR-plug, which looks kinda like this:

[image: XLR connector]

Hope, that this helps you a bit.

Comment: the km184 are much more longer in size....this will not work ;(

Comment: Do they fit in the Røde blimp at all? If yes, you could try to shorten the XLR connector even further by removing the outer metal shell: https://www.dropbox.com/s/282rrssf0ssnr6x/IMG_0727.JPG



Comment: There isn´t a pic nor more, but i own 90° XLR connector by Kortwich, which are amazingly small and the fit perfectly inside the blimp with the CM3